# Pushing and iterating over array to display history report?

Tags: javascript

I am building a project to help kids in school learn how to read faster. I have borrowed bits of code here and there and mixed up a timer and text generator.

Now I am trying to build a function to generate a summary of the latest reading time (so that they can see progress), perhaps in the form of `<ol>`, I guess I need to iterate over an array, push into it and then display but none of that seems to work.

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  var ampm = "";
  m = checkTime(m);

  if (h > 12) {
    h = h - 12;
    ampm = " PM";
  } else if (h == 12) {
    h = 12;
    ampm = " AM";
  } else if (h < 12) {
    ampm = " AM";
  } else {
    ampm = "PM";
  };

  if (h == 0) {
    h = 12;
  }

  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ampm;
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
    startTime()
  }, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  };
  return i;
}

function startDate() {
  var d = new Date();
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()] + " | " + [d.getMonth() + 1] + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
}

var quotes = ["",
  "\"Dude, suckin' at something is the first step at being sorta good at something.\"<br>-  Jake <small><em>(Adventure Time)</em></small>",
  "\"Either I will find a way, or I will make one.\"<br> - Philip Sidney",
  "\"Our greatest weakness lies in giving up. The most certain way to succeed is always to try just one more time.\"<br>- Thomas A. Edison",
  "\"You are never too old to set another goal or to dream a new dream.\"<br>- C.S Lewis",
  "\"If you can dream it, you can do it.\"<br>- Walt Disney",
  "\"Never give up, for that is just the place and time that the tide will turn.\"<br>- Harriet Beecher Stowe",
  "\"I know where I'm going and I know the truth, and I don't have to be what you want me to be. I'm free to be what I want.\"<br>- Muhammad Ali",
  "\"If you always put limit on everything you do, physical or anything else. It will spread into your work and into your life. There are no limits. There are only plateaus, and you must not stay there, you must go beyond them.\"<br>- Bruce Lee",
];

function genQuote() {
  var quote = document.getElementById("quote");
  var generate = document.getElementById("gen");
  generate.addEventListener("click", changeText);
  quote.innerHTML = quotes[0];

  function changeText() {
    var searchTerm = quote.innerHTML;
    var index = quotes.indexOf(searchTerm) + 1;
    if (index == quotes.length) index = 0;
    var result = quotes[index];
    quote.innerHTML = result;
    return;
  }
}

var startTime, endTime;

function start() {
  startTime = performance.now();
};

function end() {
  endTime = performance.now();
  var timeDiff = endTime - startTime;
  timeDiff /= 1000;

  var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
  var minutes = Math.round(seconds / 60);
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = ("You have read for:" + " " + minutes + " minutes" + " " + seconds + " seconds");
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();;
  }, 5000);
}

function report() {
  // results = [];
  // times = document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML;
  // for (i=0; i <= times.length; i++) {
  // results.push(i);
  // return results;
  // }
}
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="date"></div>
<div id="quote"></div>
<div id="get"></div>
```

Here is the HTML in case that help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <title>2 Cool 4 School</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <body onload="startTime(); startDate()">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="date"></div>
      <div id="display"></div>
      <div id="content">
        <p id="quote">"the people who are crazy enough to think they can change the world are the ones who do." <br/>- Steve Jobs</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b-nav">
      <ul>
        <button id="genone"class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="start()">Start</button>
        <button id="gen" onclick="genQuote()">Continue reading</button>
        <button id="genthree" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="report()">History</button>
        <button id="gentwo" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="end()">End</button>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Right now when I click Stars the timer runs, when I click End after that I am provided "you have read for: 0 minutes 4 seconds"

I would like to get a report of this something like:

1. you have read for: 3 minutes 30 seconds
2. you have read for: 2 minutes 50 seconds
3. you have read for: 1 minutes 40 seconds

etc Hope that helps(sorry I didnt get the snippet thing)

Comment: what are you trying here `times = document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML;` ??

Comment: Can you explain your expected results a bit more?

Comment: I've added a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) of the code posted, and added some HTML elements with ids matching those searched for by the JavaScript. Please do [edit] that code so that it makes more sense and illustrates the problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

the biggest problem is placing "return results;" inside your loop. which means your loop never fully executes. move that outside your loop.

secondly, your report() function is just going to return a string of numbers, [0,1,2,3,4...] which is probably not what you are looking for.